# How to install Sentinel as a non-root user?

Tags: software-installation, permissions

Trying to install Sentinel as non-root.

Need to install

```
git clone https://github.com/geekcash/node-sentinel.git && cd node-sentinel
```

I'm trying to do it as new user, so I `make -su newuser`, but I have next issue after command:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'node-sentinel': Permission denied
```

I should mention that I already have Sentinel installed in root directory, but now I need that for newuser.